# How do I overcome AppCheck failed on iOS 15.2 Firebase v8.11.0?

Tags: ios, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui, firebase-app-check

Has anyone encountered this issue with Firebase version 8.11.0. I am unsure how to suppress it for my app. Do I need to integrate AppCheck into my project?

```
[Firebase/Firestore][I-FST000001] AppCheck failed: 'The operation couldn’t be completed. Too many attempts. Underlying error: The operation couldn’t be completed. The server responded with an error: 
 - URL: https://firebaseappcheck.googleapis.com/v1beta/projects/............
 - HTTP status code: 400 
 - Response body: {
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "App not registered: ...............",
    "status": "FAILED_PRECONDITION"
  }
}
```

Comment: If my answer addressed your question, please consider accepting and up-voting it. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer.

Comment: @MonaliGhotekar Can't you integrate App Check with the other method ([App Attest](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/ios/app-attest-provider?hl=en&authuser=0)) instead?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same issue I solved by adding a p8 file to the firebase app check like this

### Create a private key for DeviceCheck

- Create new private key or enable **DeviceCheck** in your existing key from [Apple Developers Account](https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/authkeys/add)

  [image: AppCheck]

### Upload key to DeviceCheck in Firebase console

- Navigate to [App Check](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/appcheck) section of firebase console
- Switch to **Apps** tab
- Select the iOS app that you would like to integrate DeviceCheck provider with
- Select DeviceCheck
- Provide the private key you created in the previous step
  [image: AppCheck]
- You can find you private key Id in your [Apple developers account](https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/authkeys/review/)
- Save

## AppAttest

AppAttest is another built-in AppCheck provider for Apple platforms. Follow below steps to integrate AppAttest in your apps.

**You will need Xcode 12.5+ to use App Attest.**

### Add AppAttest to your firebase project

- Navigate to [App Check](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/appcheck) section of firebase console
- Switch to **Apps** tab
- Select the iOS app that you would like to integrate AppAttest provider with
- Check AppAttest and save
  [image: AppCheck]
- Save

Answer (score 1):

Register your apps to use App Check with the DeviceCheck provider in the Project Settings > App Check section of the Firebase console. You will need to provide the private key you created in the previous step.

You usually need to register all your project's apps, because once you enable enforcement for a Firebase product, only registered apps will be able to access the product's backend resources.

You can refer to the [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/ios/devicecheck-provider) for more information.

Answer (score -2):

the easiest way is delete your app from firebase and recreate it.