# What am I missing for setting up firebase app check on ios and react native / expo?

Tags: ios, expo, react-native-firebase, firebase-app-check

I'm sure I've *set up the app in the firebase console*.

I'm trying to set up app check for our ios app. I'm intending to use it to secure a functions call. I've verified that the function works when I don't throw an error on looking for the app check. However, I'm not seeing `context.app`.

I've added a sanity check by calling `getToken` on the mobile app and I'm running into the following error

```
NativeFirebaseError: [appCheck/token-error] The operation couldn’t be completed. Too many attempts. Underlying error: The operation couldn’t be completed. The server responded with an error: 
 - URL: https://firebaseappcheck.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<Redacted>/apps/<Redacted>:exchangeDeviceCheckToken 
 - HTTP status code: 400 
 - Response body: {
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "App not registered: <Redacted>.",
    "status": "FAILED_PRECONDITION"
  }
}
```

I've checked the firebase app check console and I have the following:

1. The appcheck console has this app registered with device check and app attest.
2. The device check configuration uses the p8 file I set up for device check in the apple developer portal.
3. The id that I redacted above is the id in the relevant google.plist file.

The only thing I'm not doing that's in the docs is setting up debug tokens, but my understanding is that's for CI and simulator environments. I'm testing on a physical device with an expo development build. Is there something I'm missing for set up?

Here is the init code I'm using

```js
async function initiateAppCheckSecurity () {
    const provider = appCheck().newReactNativeFirebaseAppCheckProvider();
    await provider.configure({
        /** @todo set up android */
        apple: {
            provider: 'appAttestWithDeviceCheckFallback',
        },
    });
    await appCheck().initializeAppCheck({ provider, isTokenAutoRefreshEnabled: false });

    // sanity check
    const blah = await appCheck().getToken();
        // error thrown here.
    console.log({ blah });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue. I fixed by recreating a p8 file and follow this thread.

[How do I overcome AppCheck failed on iOS 15.2 Firebase v8.11.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70809709/how-do-i-overcome-appcheck-failed-on-ios-15-2-firebase-v8-11-0)

Answer (score 0):

I don't particularly understand why this happened, but the issue resolved itself this morning and I did nothing with the project since I posted this. My guess is that there is some caching going on, but I didn't see anything in docs regarding it.

If someone finds a mention about this in the docs, I'll mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: They have some 24hrs cache which might be the issue.